Myysql Binlog Child Table Records Deletion Tracking
I am currently working on a project to keep a record of all the Database changes in a storage system.
In Mysql ,when a parent record is deleted the binlogs do not show records of child table records that are affected(based on ON DELETE Action). Has anyone tried implementing any feature such that the hadoop store has a record of all the changes in the database?
Consider I am storing all the binlogs in hadoop.I want the cascaded changes to also appear in my file.
